# Relacionar tabela de sub consulta com consulta principal

Tags: mysql, query, sql-select, select, sql-table

SGDB: MySql.

PROBLEMA: Preciso de alguma forma relacionar a subquery (Sendo tabela e campo em destaque Funcionario.codZona1) com a tabela "Zona", que está na consulta principal. Existe alguma maneira?

---

Tabela "ZONA": 
Contém todas as Zonas da cidade.

Campos da tabela: 
"codigo" (INT - Chave - autoincrement - código identificador da tabela),
nomeZona (VARCHAR - nome das Zona)

Dados:
 Código | NomeZona

```
1 | Zona Centro-Oeste 
2 | Zona Centro-Sul 
3 | Zona Leste 
4 | Zona Norte 
5 | Zona Oeste 
6 | Zona Sul
```

---

Tabelas "ITINERARIO", "ITINERARIODEPENDENTE", "ITINERARIOEXTRA" (TODAS IGUAIS):
Contém lista de funcionários e Zonas onde moram.

Campos da tabela: 
"Codigo" (INT - Chave - autoincrement), 
"codFuncionario" (INT - Código do funcionário),
"codZona1" (INT - Código da zona onde o funcionário está alocado)

Dados: Codigo | codFuncionario | codZona1

```
1 | 1 | 5 
2 | 2 | 1
3 | 3 | 4
4 | 4 | 3
5 | 5 | 5
6 | 6 | 6
7 | 7 | 2
8 | 8 | 4
9 | 9 | 5
```

---

A consulta abaixo tenta exibir a quantidade de "codFuncionario" (Feita por COUNT )existentes nas tabelas "ITINERARIO", "ITINERARIODEPENDENTE" E "ITINERARIOEXTRA" que estão sendo unificadas por UNION, sendo somadas em uma Sub Consulta no trecho "SELECT SUM(qtdPessoas) AS ttPessoas FROM (". E em uma consulta principal (que está acima da SOMA de "qtdPessoas"), está a "nomeZona", que devem ser relacionadas diretamente com a tabelas "ITINERARIO", "ITINERARIODEPENDENTE" E "ITINERARIOEXTRA" pelos campos "codZona1" com o campo "codigo" da tabela "Zona".

```
    SELECT Zona.nomeZona, ( 
        SELECT SUM(qtdPessoas) AS ttPessoas FROM (
            SELECT      COUNT(DISTINCT Itinerario.codFuncionario) AS qtdPessoas
            FROM        Itinerario
            WHERE       Itinerario.codZona1 = Zona.codigo  
            UNION ALL
            SELECT      COUNT(DISTINCT ItinerarioDependente.codDependente) AS qtdPessoas
            FROM        ItinerarioDependente
            WHERE       ItinerarioDependente.codZona1 = Zona.codigo  
            UNION ALL
            SELECT      COUNT(DISTINCT ItinerarioExtra.codExtra) AS qtdPessoas
            FROM        ItinerarioExtra 
            WHERE       ItinerarioExtra.codZona1 = Zona.codigo)
        AS tbP1) AS QtdFuncionarios
    FROM Zona
```

Pois da maneira que estou fazendo, está resultado assim:

```
Zona Centro-Oeste   900
Zona Centro-Sul     900
Zona Leste          900
Zona Norte          900
Zona Oeste          900
Zona Sul            900
```

Ao invés de vir assim:

```
Zona Centro-Oeste   100
Zona Centro-Sul     200
Zona Leste          100
Zona Norte          400
Zona Oeste          50
Zona Sul            50
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT Zona.nomeZona, ( 
        SELECT SUM(qtdPessoas) AS ttPessoas FROM (
            SELECT      COUNT(DISTINCT Itinerario.codFuncionario) AS qtdPessoas,
                        Itinerario.codZona1 
            FROM        Itinerario
            GROUP BY       Itinerario.codZona1  
            UNION ALL
            SELECT      COUNT(DISTINCT ItinerarioDependente.codDependente) AS qtdPessoas,
                        ItinerarioDependente.codZona1
            FROM        ItinerarioDependente
            GROUP BY  ItinerarioDependente.codZona1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT      COUNT(DISTINCT ItinerarioExtra.codExtra) AS qtdPessoas,
                        ItinerarioExtra.codZona1
            FROM        ItinerarioExtra 
            GROUP BY       ItinerarioExtra.codZona1)
        AS tbP1
        WHERE tbP1.codZona1 = Zona.codigo) AS QtdFuncionarios
    FROM Zona
```

Como nosso amigo acima disse seria assim a consulta;